# Aggregate jquery.cookie.js is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

This is my code:

```
$(function() {

  if ($.cookie('is_legal') == "yes") {
    //legal!
  } else {
    document.location = "http://www.alcoholinformate.org.mx/";
  }
});


$("#yes").click(function(){
  $.cookie('is_legal', 'yes', { expires: 1});
  $('#agegate').hide();
});

$("#no").click(function(){
  document.location = "http://www.alcoholinformate.org.mx/";

});
```

There are two buttons obviously yes and no, when I load my page the console shows

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

on this line

```
if ($.cookie('is_legal') == "yes") {
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you include the cookie plugin?

Comment: @epascarello yes its included

Comment: Correctly? `console.log($.cookie);`

Comment: @epascarello it log as undefined

Comment: Than you did not load the cookie javascript file!